# Transfer purchased songs without syncing in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

My iPhone is synced to another computer.  I bought some songs on iTunes and now can't figure out how to transfer the songs to my iPhone!  If I try to sync it will warn me that it will first delete my existing songs which I don't want to do.  So how can I transfer the songs I just bought?

Comment: More information please.

The iPhone is synced to Computer A.
You bought some songs on Computer B.

You bought them with the same account that you use for Computer A right?

Do you want to move the songs from your iPhone to Computer B and then sync?

Do you want to move the new songs to Computer A and then sync?

Comment: That scenario is correct.  What I want to do is put the songs I bought on comp B (in iTunes) and put them on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Sharepod](http://www.getsharepod.com/download/).  Add/remove/access music from your iPhone without using iTunes.

Comment: I never got around to trying this, but it looks like it will do the trick.